# How can I make the next printf() to print on the same line and not below it?

Tags: c, debugging

I recently started learning C, and I decided to make a calculator program that is quite easy for a user to use:

```
#include"stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    char c;
    scanf("%d%c%d",&a,&c,&b);
    switch(c)
    {
        case '+':
        printf("=%d",a+b);
        break;

        case '-':
        printf("=%d",a-b);
        break;

        case '*':
        printf("=%d",a*b);
        break;

        case '/':
        printf("=%d",a/b);
        break;

        case '%':
        printf("=%d",a%b);
        break;

        default:
        printf("\nWhat the heck is %c supposed to mean??",c);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get this problem when I execute it. The output statements get printed one line below, rather than continuing on the same line, even though I didn't use a `\n` in the `printf()` command.

```
4/2
=2
```

How can I fix this, and make the =2 print on the same line?

Comment: The user types the newline; you can't stop that happening, and therefore your program's output occurs on the next line.  You could echo all the input plus the result on a single line, though.

Comment: *"You could echo all the input plus the result on a single line, though."* Can you please explain what you mean here?

Comment: `printf("%+%d=%d\n", a, b, a+b)`

Comment: After the `scanf()` — which should be error checked — and before the `switch`, add: `printf("%d %c %d = ", a, c, b);`.  Then the print operations in the `switch` complete the output (drop the `=` from those operations though).  Or you could simply calculated a number, `d` in each case of the `switch` and then do the whole print in one after the switch: `printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", a, c, b, d);`

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the first line is the input user has given to the console whereas the second line is the actual printf (which actually doesn't print any newline character).

As the user inputs `4/2` he presses enter and is what that gets printed in the console.

If you don't want this to happen, use `getchar()` function thrice two get the three characters, and print just after receciving them.  You will although have to put a little bit complex code to identify the end of first number, the first operational character `+-*/` and the ending of the second number (You can use a space character for that). This will ultimately print your input like `4/2 =2`.

Or as mentioned in the above comments,

what you can really do is something easy: print the input along with the output like: `printf("%d%c%d=%d",,a,c,b,a+b);` but this approach will actually bring in the output as well as the original input to the console.

Comment: *"You will although have to put a little bit complex code to identify the end of first number, the first operational character +-*/ and the ending of the second number.*" How would you suggest identifying the "end of the second number" in your approach?

Comment: Oh forgot to mention that, a space character might help. will add that in the answer.

Comment: On most systems, `getchar()` won't return anything until after the user has pressed the return key, by which time the damage has been done.  You might use one of the platform-specific 'read a single character without waiting for the newline' functions, which might be sufficient to do the job.  But you have to know which platform you're on to know which function(s) to use.

Answer (score 1):

using termios:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>


int main()
{
    int a,b, i, j;
    char c, str[10];
    struct termios term, term_orig;
    if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term_orig)) {
         printf("tcgetattr failed\n");
         return -1;
    }
    term = term_orig;
    term.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    term.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term)) {
          printf("tcsetattr failed\n");
          return (-1);
   }
  for (i =0; i < 3; i++)     
  {
      switch (i)
      {
        case 0:
           for(j = 0;; j++)
           {
              str[j] = getchar();
              if (isdigit(str[j]))
                   putchar(str[j]);
              else
                    break;    
           }
           str[j] =0;
           a = atoi(str);
           break;
      case 1:
         do {
         c = fgetc(stdin);
         }  while ( c == ' ');
          putchar(c);
         break;

      case 2:
         j = 0;
         do { 
            str[j] = getchar();
            putchar(str[j]);
        }  while ( str[j] == ' ');
        for(j = 0;; j++)
        {
         str[j] = getchar();
         if (isdigit(str[j]))
              putchar(str[j]);
         else
             break;    
        }
        str[j] =0;
        b = atoi(str);
        break;
     }
}
switch(c)//.......


 if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term_orig)) {
     printf("tcsetattr failed\n");
     return -1;
  }
```